# Call a method from another class for which I cannot inherit

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I want to create a program to update a player's bank account balance after a purchase or sale is made. This player is part of my explaining environment and can therefore be called from the `Environment` class with the `get_user()` method.

When the Player makes a purchase or sale, he must pay a variable tax, the amount of which is given by the `Environment` class with the `get_tax()` method.

How can I call the "get_tax()" method from the Player class?

Here is my full code with its comments

```
from typing import Any
import random


class BankAccount:
    name: str
    balance: float

    def __init__(self, name: str, balance: float) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance


class Player:
    name: str

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.account_bank = None

    def set_account(self, name, balance) -> None:
        self.account_bank = BankAccount(name, balance)

    def get_account(self) -> BankAccount:
        return self.account_bank

    def buy_something(self, price):
        tax = self.get_tax()                    # How can I get here the amount of the tax from my "Environment" class ?
        self.get_account().balance -= (price * (1 + tax))

    def sell_something(self, price):
        tax = self.get_tax()                    # How can I get here the amount of the tax from my "Environment" class ?
        self.get_account().balance += (price * (1 + tax))

    def action(self, choice, price):
        if choice == 1:
            self.buy_something(price)
        if choice == 2:
            self.sell_something(price)
        else:
            pass


class Environment:

    def __init__(self, tax_min, tax_max):
        self.tax_min = tax_min
        self.tax_max = tax_max

        self.players = {}

    def get_tax(self):
        return random.uniform(self.tax_min, self.tax_max)

    def add_player(self, name: str) -> None:
        kwargs = {'name': name}
        self.players[name] = Player(**kwargs)

    def get_user(self, name: str) -> Player:    # Here I need "-> Player" to be able to call the methods of the "Player" class after calling this method "get_user" and because of which I cannot make an inheritance relation between my Player and Environment classes
        return self.players[name]


env = Environment(0.10, 0.20)                   # Created an environment with a tax varying between 10 and 20%

player_name = 'jason'
env.add_player(player_name)                     # Create player 'jason'

jason = env.get_user(player_name)
jason.set_account('my_account', 100)            # Adds Jason an account with $ 100

jason.action(1, 20)                             # buy something for 20 dollars

print(jason.get_account().__dict__)
```

Comment: What is preventing you from calling `env.get_tax()`?

Comment: The player would need to be told about the environment that it's in. You could give it a reference when you create the `Player`. Should it be the player's job to know the tax rate though? That sounds like that should be the store's responsibility.

Comment: I see.
I would like the tax amount to be set by the environment and then be called at any time...
Should I pass my "env" instance as an argument to my "action()" method, then to my "buy_something()" and "sell_somthing()" methods, or it's better to directly call "env.get_tax()" in the methods where j do I need it?

Comment: "Should I pass my "env" instance as an argument to my "action" method": If you were going to go that route, and if the environment won't change, I'd just give `env` to the `Player` directly, then you can refer to the `env` as `self.env` from within the Player. If you create a store class though, I think it would make more sense for the store to handle purchases, and for the store to calculate the tax for the player.

Comment: @Carcigenicate
In my case, the players depend on the store which is represented in my code by the Environment class. The amount of the tax varies over time. But if 2 players want to buy or sell at the same time, they will have to pay the same tax

Answer (score 0):

To use methods from 'Player' class, you can use super() function.

```
def get_user(self, name: str) -> Player:    
    return self.players[name]
```

But you have to inherit the 'Player' class in 'Environment' function like this first:

```
class Environment(Player):
```

There is one problem. If you write __init__() function in the 'Environment' class again, it will overwrite the __init__() function of 'Player' class. To avoid this,
you can use super() function.

```
class Environment(Player):
    def __init__(self, tax_min, tax_max):
        super().__init__(**kwargs) # you don't need 'self' here
```

Remember you have to write super() function under __init__() function.
Now, methods in 'Player' class become methods of'Environment' class and this become legal to use.

```
x = Environment(0.10,0.20)
x.get_account() # a method from 'Player' class
```

In this part of your code, I recommend you to divide it into a new class(eg,class Action). And use the same inheritance way like before to get tax values from 'Environment' class.

```
def buy_something(self, price):
    tax = self.get_tax()                   
    self.get_account().balance -= (price * (1 + tax))

def sell_something(self, price):
    tax = self.get_tax()                   
    self.get_account().balance += (price * (1 + tax))

def action(self, choice, price):
    if choice == 1:
        self.buy_something(price)
    if choice == 2:
        self.sell_something(price)
    else:
        pass
```

Is there anything you don't understand?

Comment: Your approach is very interesting. I test this as soon as possible !

Comment: I followed your recommendation but I cannot call the `get_tax` method from the `Player` class. I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'get_tax'`

Comment: Should I call the `get_tax` method in my `Player` class as follows? `self.get_tax()`

Comment: I think it is impossible. Instead of calling each other, try this. Place get_tax() method in main 'Parent class'. Then inherit parent methods in 'Child' class. Next create a new class (e.g. Grandson) which will inherit 'Child' class. In that way, 'Grandson' class will inherit all the methods from 'Child' class and 'Parent' class.