# Get the parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to create nested classes. I took as an example cities that are located in a state, which itself belongs to a country. I want from my Country class, to be able to add States, or from my State class to add Cities, etc ... So I made the following code:

```
from typing import Dict


class City:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.inhabitants = {}

    def add_inhabitant(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        kwargs = {'name': name, 'age': age}
        self.inhabitants[name] = kwargs

    def get_inhabitant(self, name: str) -> Dict:
        return self.inhabitants[name]


class State:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.cities = {}

    def add_city(self, name: str) -> None:
        kwargs = {'name': name}
        self.cities[name] = City(**kwargs)

    def get_city(self, name: str) -> City:
        return self.cities[name]


class Country:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.states = {}

    def add_state(self, name: str) -> None:
        kwargs = {'name': name}
        self.states[name] = State(**kwargs)

    def get_state(self, name: str) -> State:
        return self.states[name]
```

I can thus from my Country class get a State, then from my State class get a city, etc ... it works fine

```
usa = Country('USA')

usa.add_state('Texas')
texas = usa.get_state('Texas')

texas.add_city('Houston')
houston = texas.get_city('Houston')

houston.add_inhabitant('Jason', 43)
houston.add_inhabitant('Elon', 38)

print(houston.__dict__)
```

I now wish from a city to obtain the state where it is located as well as the country to which it belongs. How can I do this?

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
houston.get_state()
houston.get_country()
```

Comment: Terminology note: these aren't "nested classes" or "inner classes". Also, the term "parent class" implies inheritance, which you don't use here. You are using *composition*

Comment: In any case, if you want your `City` objects to keep track of the `State` that created them, *you have to add that logic somehow*

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `**kwargs` like that?

Comment: You have to define what the state the city is in, if I were you I would use two dictionarys, one for `state : country` and one for `city : state` and if needed another dictionary for, `city : country`

Comment: The answer is essentially the same as for your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67888200/11946287 (see the upvoted comment)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm starting to understand what I'm looking for... I think I need to rephrase my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to the parent in each child.

```
class City:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.state = kwargs['state']
        self.inhabitants = {}

    def add_inhabitant(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        kwargs = {'name': name, 'age': age}
        self.inhabitants[name] = kwargs

    def get_inhabitant(self, name: str) -> Dict:
        return self.inhabitants[name]


class State:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.country = kwargs['country']
        self.cities = {}

    def add_city(self, name: str) -> None:
        kwargs = {'name': name, 'state': self}
        self.cities[name] = City(**kwargs)

    def get_city(self, name: str) -> City:
        return self.cities[name]

class Country:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.states = {}

    def add_state(self, name: str) -> None:
        kwargs = {'name': name, 'country': self}
        self.states[name] = State(**kwargs)

    def get_state(self, name: str) -> State:
        return self.states[name]
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar, but I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'City' object has no attribute 'get_state'"

Comment: Where are you getting that from? `get_state()` is a method of `Country`, you shouldn't call it on a `City`. If you want the state that the city is in, just use `houston.city`

Comment: You can add the method if you want: `def get_state(self): return self.state`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar